# Dropbox sync api

Tags: ios, objective-c, dropbox-api

I am adding a observer to filesystem and Dbfile, but I am getting error that file already open. Please tell me where to close my file.
Below is my code:

```
[filesystem addObserver:self forPathAndChildren:pathDB block:^(DBObserver complete){////observer to folder
                DBError *error= nil;
                NSLog(@"File(s) %@ changed!",pathDB);

                 DBFile *file=[filesystem openFile:pathDB error:&error];
                [file addObserver:self block:^() { ///observer to file


                    DBFileStatus *newerStatus = file.newerStatus;
                    if (newerStatus)
                    {
                        if (!newerStatus.cached)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"newerStatus.cached == NO; this means the file downloading");

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Update to the newly available version and print it out
                            [file update:nil];

                            NSData *fileData = [file readData:nil];
                            [fileData writeToFile:[[appDelegate.directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Projects"]  stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",path] atomically:YES];

                            [file close];

                    }

                }];

            }];
```

Comment: Cross-linking with https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/201879539-Sync-API-File-open-Issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm, but my guess is that the error comes from this line:

```
DBFile *file=[filesystem openFile:pathDB error:&error];
```

That runs every time there's a change to `pathDB`, but you don't always close the file, so sometimes it will already be open.

I can't figure out what you're trying to do with your code, since you're setting up an observer on a path and then an observer on the file at that path... also, I'm pretty sure this code wouldn't compile, since you appear to be missing a closing curly brace.

One of the observers is probably redundant. Maybe all you want is this (no path observer at all)?

```
DBFile *file=[filesystem openFile:pathDB error:&error];
[file addObserver:self block:^() { ///observer to file
    DBFileStatus *newerStatus = file.newerStatus;
    if (newerStatus)
    {
        if (!newerStatus.cached)
        {
            NSLog(@"newerStatus.cached == NO; this means the file downloading");
        }
        else
        {
            // Update to the newly available version and print it out
            [file update:nil];

            NSData *fileData = [file readData:nil];
            [fileData writeToFile:[[appDelegate.directoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Projects"]  stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@",path] atomically:YES];
            [file close];
        }
    }
}];
```

The only reason I can think of to have both observers is if you want to handle the case where the file doesn't exist. In that case, the code you have might be close, but you'll need to not add an observer to the file if you already have one.

Comment: Yes The error is coming when I am trying to open a file which is already opened.But I am closing a file everywhere where I opened it but sometime the observer doesn't go inside the block and its calling two to three time for a single file changing in the server.I am trying to do simple syncing

Comment: Continuing my comment if I add a observer only to a file then its not changing when the file is changed in the dropbox server thats why I added observer to Filesystem.What I want to do here is I am taking some paths from filemanager and when that exact file with that path changes I am downloading the content and writing that updated content to my directory of app.

Comment: Sorry I missed one braces when I was pasting the code.Here is my code

Comment: I couldn't able to paste the whole code here but i will try with only one observer (File).Thank you for your response.:)

Comment: Thanks for your solution I have removed one observer and its working fine ...Thanks a lott You saved my life

Comment: Have you looked at this github project? https://github.com/MindPreview/KRCloudSync